# Parameterised Query Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, parameters

I've been having trouble getting parametrised queries to work. The code is working fine without parameterised SQL.

The error I'm getting is `Must declare the scalar variable @RegNo`.

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbsBank.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

Dim queryString As String = "SELECT PAC FROM Customers WHERE Registration_No = @RegNo"

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(queryString, conn)
Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@RegNo", SqlDbType.Int)
param.Value = mtbPassword.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn)

dTable = New DataTable

Try
    adap.Fill(dTable)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: you have an extra `)` at the end of your query.

Comment: I forgot to remove it after trying something, it's not the cause of the problem though.

Comment: You are declaring and making a `Command` object but never using it. That is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You build your `Command` object but never use it. So your `DataAdapter` never has the parameter definition.

Replace

```
Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn)
```

with

```
Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```

This should most likely solve your problem

Comment: Ah, Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.